# Webcrawler - Duplicates and weird count

Tags: f#

I've stole some code from "Expert F# 2.0", that shows how to build a webcrawler, using MailboxProcessor. As you see, then I have a print expression at line 23, that prints the current number of urls in the `visited` Set. Also the number of urls to crawl is limited by 49.

```
open System
open System.Net
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.WebExtensions

let getLinks (txt:string) =
 [ for m in Regex.Matches(txt, "href=\s*\"[^\"h]*(http://[^&\"]*)\"")  -> m.Groups.Item(1).Value ]

let collectLinks (url:string) =
  async { let web = new WebClient()
          let! data = web.AsyncDownloadString <| Uri url
          let links = getLinks data
          return links }

let urlCollector =
  MailboxProcessor.Start(fun self ->
    let rec waitForUrl (visited : Set<string>) =
      async { // Checks whether we have reached the limit of pages to crawl
              if visited.Count < 50 then

                // Waits for a URL...
                let! url = self.Receive()
                printfn "%A | %A" visited.Count url

                // If not the URL already has been crawled...
                if not (visited.Contains url) then

                  // Start
                  do! Async.StartChild(
                        async { let! links = collectLinks url
                                Seq.iter self.Post links}) |> Async.Ignore
                return! waitForUrl (visited.Add url) }
    waitForUrl Set.empty)


urlCollector.Post "http://news.google.com/"
```

That's seems alright eh? - But now the output looks like:

```
0 | "http://news.google.com/"
1 | "http://www.gstatic.com/news/img/favicon.ico"
2 | "http://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=nm"
3 | "http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/"
4 | "http://docs.google.com/?tab=no"
5 | "http://www.google.com/reader/?tab=ny"
6 | "http://sites.google.com/?tab=n3"
7 | "http://www.google.com/intl/en/options/"
7 | "http://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en"
8 | "http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2011/aug/07/tottenham-riots-police-had-not-anticipated-violence"
9 | "http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2011-08-07/london-rioters-clash-with-police-loot-in-tottenham-after-shooting-death.html"
10 | "http://www.hindustantimes.com/Rioters-battle-police-after-shooting-protest/Article1-730371.aspx"
11 | "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/8687177/Tottenham-riot-live.html"
12 | "http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2011/aug/07/tottenham-riots-police-had-not-anticipated-violence"
12 | "http://www.montrealgazette.com/London+wakes+riot+aftermath/5218849/story.html"
13 | "http://themediablog.typepad.com/the-media-blog/2011/08/daily-mail-tottenham-violence-twitter.html"
14 | "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Tottenham_riots"
15 | "http://www.babnet.net/festivaldetail-37897.asp"
16 | "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9UImSbegj4"
17 | "http://www.babnet.net/festivaldetail-37897.asp"
17 | "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9UImSbegj4"
17 | "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/8687177/Tottenham-riot-live.html"
17 | "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/crime/8687177/Tottenham-riot-live.html"
17 | "http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2011/aug/07/tottenham-riots-police-had-not-anticipated-violence"
17 | "http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/2011/aug/07/tottenham-riots-police-had-not-anticipated-violence"
17 | "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-14436001"
18 | "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-14436001"
18 | "http://www.kbc.co.ke/news.asp?nid=71755"
19 | "http://www.kbc.co.ke/news.asp?nid=71755"
19 | "http://news.sky.com/skynews/Home/UK-News/Tottenham-Riots-Simmering-Anger-Erupts-In-North-London-After-Protest-At-Mans-Shooting-Death/Article/201108116045172?f=rss"
20 | "http://news.sky.com/skynews/Home/UK-News/Tottenham-Riots-Simmering-Anger-Erupts-In-North-London-After-Protest-At-Mans-Shooting-Death/Article/201108116045172?f=rss"
20 | "http://www.irishtimes.com/newspaper/breaking/2011/0807/breaking2.html?via=mr"
21 | "http://www.irishtimes.com/newspaper/breaking/2011/0807/breaking2.html?via=mr"
21 | "http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/story/2011/08/07/tottenham-riot.html"
22 | "http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/story/2011/08/07/tottenham-riot.html"
22 | "http://www.newsday.com/news/police-officer-hospitalized-7-injured-in-uk-riot-1.3079769"
23 | "http://www.newsday.com/news/police-officer-hospitalized-7-injured-in-uk-riot-1.3079769"
23 | "http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/44049721/ns/world_news-europe/"
24 | "http://www.msnbc.msn.com/id/44049721/ns/world_news-europe/"
24 | "http://www.timeslive.co.za/world/2011/08/07/eight-london-police-hospitalised-after-riots"
25 | "http://www.timeslive.co.za/world/2011/08/07/eight-london-police-hospitalised-after-riots"
25 | "http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/europe/08/07/uk.riots/"
26 | "http://www.cnn.com/2011/WORLD/europe/08/07/uk.riots/"
26 | "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2023348/Tottenham-anarchy-Grim-echo-1985-Broadwater-farm-riot.html"
27 | "http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2023348/Tottenham-anarchy-Grim-echo-1985-Broadwater-farm-riot.html"
27 | "http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/top-stories/2011/08/06/tottenham-riot-protesters-torch-police-cars-shops-and-a-bus-115875-23325724/"
28 | "http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/top-stories/2011/08/06/tottenham-riot-protesters-torch-police-cars-shops-and-a-bus-115875-23325724/"
28 | "http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/images-of-the-destruction-from-londons-tottenham-riots/article2122026/"
29 | "http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/world/images-of-the-destruction-from-londons-tottenham-riots/article2122026/"
29 | "http://thelede.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/shops-and-cars-burn-in-anti-police-riot-in-london/"
30 | "http://thelede.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/shops-and-cars-burn-in-anti-police-riot-in-london/"
30 | "http://www.stuff.co.nz/world/5403614/Crowds-attack-police-after-UK-protest"
31 | "http://www.stuff.co.nz/world/5403614/Crowds-attack-police-after-UK-protest"
31 | "http://www.google.com/hostednews/afp/article/ALeqM5jOCV_DVSYR1S50v6vdSBjsR5H9Jw?docId=CNG.36dce69df0a155bfd2fa1a3a5f92f6e1.5c1"
32 | "http://www.google.com/hostednews/afp/article/ALeqM5jOCV_DVSYR1S50v6vdSBjsR5H9Jw?docId=CNG.36dce69df0a155bfd2fa1a3a5f92f6e1.5c1"
32 | "http://fallenscoop.com/16993/tottenham-riot-2011-north-london-burns-after-protest-of-mark-duggan"
33 | "http://fallenscoop.com/16993/tottenham-riot-2011-north-london-burns-after-protest-of-mark-duggan"
33 | "http://www.thedailybeast.com/cheats/2011/08/07/riots-grip-north-london.html"
34 | "http://www.thedailybeast.com/cheats/2011/08/07/riots-grip-north-london.html"
34 | "http://www.thehindu.com/news/article2333142.ece"
35 | "http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/article.cgi?f=/g/a/2011/08/07/bloomberg1376-LPHCT11A1I4H01-3ULNPF643I4ERSIU09MO54CQ4B.DTL"
36 | "http://online.wsj.com/community/groups/question-day-229/topics/do-you-agree-sps-decision?commentid=2864110"
37 | "http://www.businessweek.com/ap/financialnews/D9OUMJVO1.htm"
38 | "http://www.cnn.com/2011/BUSINESS/08/06/global.economy.cnn/"
39 | "http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/opinion/editorials/ct-edit-credit-20110806,0,6468631.story"
40 | "http://www.foxbusiness.com/markets/2011/08/07/treasury-hits-back-against-sp-downgrade/"
41 | "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_%26_Poor%27s"
42 | "http://www.usatoday.com/money/companies/management/2011-08-07-verizon-strike_n.htm"
43 | "http://www.businessweek.com/ap/financialnews/D9OV028O3.htm"
44 | "http://www.nbcnewyork.com/news/local/Verizon-Workers-Demonstrate-in-Manhattan-Part-of-45K-Worker-Strike-127087478.html"
45 | "http://www.poughkeepsiejournal.com/article/20110807/NEWS03/110807003/45K-Verizon-workers-strike-over-new-labor-contract-?odyssey=tab%7Ctopnews%7Ctext%7CPoughkeepsieJournal.com"
46 | "http://www.nypost.com/p/news/national/verizon_hit_by_strike_Ga9JjKphZrKCEAr608bqkI"
47 | "http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/07/us/07verizon.html"
48 | "http://www.ctv.ca/CTVNews/World/20110807/afghanistan-helicopter-crash-fighting-110807/"
49 | "http://abcnews.go.com/International/nato-crash-team-seal-members-killed-afghanistan/story?id=14249189"
```

What's up with all the duplicates? Also why does some of them print the same "current urls in visited Set" (like 17, 33, 34 etc.)? I'm pretty sure, that I miss something totally fundamental, but I cant figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your snippet, the printing using `printfn` is done *before* you check if the URL is already present in the set. This means that it will print the URL even if it will not be added in the next step. (You can see that it wasn't added if you look at the numbers in the left column - if the count wasn't incremented, the number on the next line is the same).

Moving `printfn` to the body of the `if` expression should give the expected results:

```
// Waits for a URL...
let! url = self.Receive()

// If not the URL already has been crawled...
if not (visited.Contains url) then
    printfn "%A | %A" visited.Count url

    // Start
```